# Why is $\int_{0}^{r}\left(\int_{\partial B(x,s)}u\ dS\right)ds=u(x)\int_{0}^{r}n\alpha(n)s^{n-1}ds$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> $\int_{B(x,r)}u\ dy=\int_{0}^{r}\left(\int_{\partial B(x,s)}u\ dS\right)ds=u(x)\int_{0}^{r}n\alpha(n)s^{n-1}ds=\alpha(n)r^nu(x)$

This appears in the proof of a theorem in the book of Evans PDE. I don't get the second equality, so in general $\int_{\partial B(x,s)}u\ dS\neq u(x)n\alpha(n)s^{n-1}$, they're only equal if we integrate both sides, am I wrong ? where does $s^{n-1}$ come from ? Is it valid only for radial symmetric $u$ ?

Comment: In the first integral you integrate by $y$, but $u=u(x)$ or $u=u(y)$?

Comment: @Tomas It is exactly written like that, but I think $u(y)dS(y)$ in the first one

Comment: which theorem is it? I'll look in my copy of Evans

Comment: @Tomas page $26$ THEOREM 2 (mean-value formulas for Laplace equation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the proof of the theorem you are refering to it was proved that the function $\phi(r):=\frac{1}{n\alpha(n) r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}u(y)dS(y)$ is constant equal to $u(x)$, i.e.
$$\phi(r)=u(x)$$
Therefore 
$$\int_{B(x,r)}udy=\int_{0}^{r}\int_{\partial B(x,s)}u(y)dS(y)ds=\int_{0}^{r}n\alpha(n)s^{n-1}\phi(s)ds=\int_{0}^{r}n\alpha(n)s^{n-1}u(x)ds$$

Comment: I didn't see in the definition of $\phi$, $r^{n-1}$ in the denominator, clear now thanks

Comment: if the answer suits you and have no further questions you can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is $u$ a harmonic function? If this is the case, then $$\frac{1}{\sigma(\partial B(x,s))}\int_{\partial B(x,s)}u\,d\sigma=u(x),$$ from the mean value property, so the second inequality follows.

Comment: @Thanks but this is the theorem itself, and there is some step in the proof of it, which i don't understand

Comment: The first part of the theorem shows exactly that, though, This part is to show the mean value property for solid integrals.